# SharePoint scheduled and unapproved page is visible to end users

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, sharepoint-2010, publish, schedule

I have an issue with one of the users of a SharePoint 2010 application concerning scheduled pages.

The user creates a page and before submitting/publishing it created a Schedule for it for a future period of time (let's say for Current Day + 1 to Current Day + 2). The problem is that after saving this schedule configuration and before even approving the page to be published, the page is already visible for the end users.

Another user with similar permissions follows exactly the same steps/process, and everything is working correctly. The page is only visible to end users between the scheduled period of time.

This issue tells me it is most likely a permissions problem, but still strikes me as one of those strange phenomena coming from SharePoint. The user which has issue has an Approval permission and the user without issue has full control permission. Is there any way that the Approval permission is somehow bypassing the whole workflow and allowing end users to see the page before the app user even approves it?